# Puppet ships with Ruby 1.8

Tags: ruby, redmine, puppet

So problem is, Puppet seems to only go with 1.8 like no matter what. But my Redmine (deployed with Puppet) would at least need 1.9.3 or higher.

Is there a sensible solution? I mean manually uninstalling Ruby after deployment and getting the right package is exactly the opposite of why we use Puppet.

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means a Ruby guy, but as far as I'm aware there is this thing called RVM which seems like it might be a solution for your issue.

Comment: it somehow cannot change it. Maybe because ruby's in use? I've got no clue. :\

Comment: I think I at one point tried to do the same thing - make Puppet use a newer version of Ruby - and what I ended up doing is issuing **which puppet** to find the Puppet binary path and then editing that file which is simply a bash script and changing the very first line to something like **#!/usr/bin/env ruby1.9.3**

Answer (score 0):

You could use Software Collections http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL  from centos. After you install SCL you can run redmine so that it uses ruby 1.9.3 rather than the systems default. SCL does not replace the default ruby it only affects the application you run with SCL.

```
yum install centos-release-SCL
yum install ruby193
scl enable ruby193 "service redmine start"
```

I don't use redmine but I'm sure you know what daemon to start. Systems don't remember anything about scl after a reboot. It would be a good idea to create script that turns it on at boot.